# Restlet dynamic serialization to Json or XML

Tags: xml, json, serialization, jaxb, restlet

When developing a RESTful webservice using the Restlet framework, I would like to serialize to JSON and XML in the most compact way as possible.

How can I dynamically decide whether to include or not an element in the answer based on the request, in the most efficient way as possible? My code would look something like that:

```
protected Representation get(bool headerIncluded,Variant variant){

      MyObject myObject = MyDao.getObject()
      MySerializer<MyObject> mySerializer = headerIncluded ? new MySerializerWithHeader() : new MySerializerWithoutHeader();
      return mySerializer.serializeToRightType(myObject,variant)

}
```

I am very keen to use JaxB, is it possible to implement such a pattern?